# What makes memory usage of explorer.exe increase?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, explorer

I run into a problem with memory after some runtime. The RAM usage of explorer increases drastically after +/- 2 weeks and with 2 or 3days to the max available.
When I restart the explorer task it is reset untill 2 or 3 days later.

After some time the issue stops for some time and then returns.

The program we made has some file handling which I would guess is where I should look.

We use QsLog for logging and QSettings for some settingfiles. Besides this we update a log txt file about every minute like the following:

```
if(txtFile == nullptr)createTxtFile();

QTextStream txtStream(txtFile);
txtStream.setCodec( QTextCodec::codecForName( "UTF-8" ) );

QString sDate = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd-MM-yyyy");
QString sTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss");
QString sTimeRunning = QString::number(dTimeRunning,'f',3).replace('.',',');

txtStream   <<sDate<<"\t"<<sTime<<"\t"<<sTimeRunning<<"\t\t"
            <<QString::number(Press->getDeflection(),'f', 5).replace('.',',')<<"\t\t"
            <<QString::number(IO->getLoad(), 'f', 2).replace('.',',')<<"\t"
            <<sTimeRunning<<"\n";
```

The problems occurred after some UI functions where moved to a different thread.

What I am looking for now is some method to help find where and why the increase in memory usage occurs.

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory (or other resource) leak somewhere.

Comment: Your process will not affect the Explorer process.  To affect the Explorer process you would need to be using DLL injection or an Explorer plug-in and have a memory leak in the injected DLL or plug-in.  These DLLs or plugins may not be ones that you know you are using.  The [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2021/11/12/windows-performance-analyzer-from-store-or-sdk/) is one tool you could consider using.